# Parent component passing it's redux prop to child, child not updating when prop does

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a parent component `A`, and a "dynamic" child component `B`. `A` is linked to the redux store, and has a prop dispatched from the store called `myItems`. `B` takes a list of children, and it iterates through them by key, so you can call it like so:

```
<B>
  <SomeView1 key="1" prop={this.props.myItems}/>
  <SomeView1 key="2" />
  <SomeView1 key="3" />
</B>
```

I am unable to pass `this.props.myItems` to the children views of B, aka from `A` to grandchild `SomeView1`. It seems to read the data once, but anytime props are updated in `A`, the changes are not reflected in `SomeView`.

```
render() {
    return (
        console.log(this.props.myItems);
        if (this.props.isUser) {
            return (
                <B
                  <SomeView1 key="1" items={this.props.myItems} />
                />
            );
        }
    );
}
```

I can use a callback, or I can pass the data to `B` which in turn passes it to `SomeView1`, however the purpose of `B` is to be a flexible component that takes any amount of components, that can in turn have any amount of props. Trying to find a better solution than passing props to B, or having dozens of callbacks for all of `B`'s childrens props.

Comment: You're going to have to show more code.

Comment: updated question with more detail.

Comment: Could you show your reducers and actions?

Comment: They definitely work, as the console.log of this.props.myItems updates accurately whenever there is a change. I think there's too much code to dig through for the reducers and actions. Should we be able to bypass B and pass from A directly to SomeView1?

Comment: Passing props from A to B is quite doable. Show the code for `A` and `B` including `mapStateToProps` if `B` is wrapped using `connect()`. My guess is either you are using the wrong prop name somewhere, or not passing the prop through in `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: Yes, passing from A to B is indeed very doable, but that's not what i want to do. I want to pass from A straight to a child of B, such as SomeView1. B is a higher order component that takes any amount of children, and lays them out, and each child has their own list of props, it would be cumbersome to add all these props to B, and then pass it in turn down to all the children.

Comment: Any reason you can't wrap SomeView1 in connect() as you've done with A?

Comment: that's what I ended up doing in, but then each SomeView1,2,3,4,5,etc  I had to connect them, rather than have it from one centralized place unfortunately.

Comment: Wait, you have more than one type of SomeView now? I'm totally lost. If you post a real-world example I could help you better.

Comment: Yes, B is a component that takes a list of children, each child has their own props that are passed from A's state, it's a pretty straightforward question methinks. Passing props from A to B's children, which are declared in A >_>